# Online check in for connecting flight (different airlines)

Tags: lhr, check-in, british-airways, air-new-zealand

I'll be flying with Air New Zealand from LAX to LHR and then from LHR to PRG with British Airways. I have both bookings available under the same Air NZ booking reference and they are all visible in my Air NZ mobile app.

I'm not sure, however, how the online check-in works in this case. I spoke today with a lady from Air NZ customer service and she said that my baggage will be transported from LAX to PRG and that I won't need to reclaim and re-check my baggage at LHR, but that I will need to check in separately for the other flight via the app. How exactly does this work? My main concern is:

- When the second online check-in asks me about my checked baggage, what do I say? Since my only checked bag will already be checked in from LAX, do I just say that I don't have any? Any chance it will cause the airline to offload the bag?

Also, am I required to print out the boarding pass when checking in online? I believe I used a boarding pass available from an airline app with a QR code when I once flew with Ryanair.

Any info about this would really help me sleep easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

Sometime you will receive your boarding pass for the two flights directly at departure, sometime you need to get your boarding pass on transfer desk: on departure they tell you about it, this is mostly due to too many hours before the second flight. Transfer desk on airside will provide you the ticket, but they will handle the baggage. Transfer desk on other side: Just ask to be sure if the baggage will follow you or if you need to get them and re-check.

On seldom case you need to do a new check-in (on check-in area). In this case having the baggage receipt will help them to control that the right baggage are on the system. It happened to me few times on "transferred flight (missed flights)". No need to get the baggage, they just need the receipt to be sure about moving the correct baggage.  But I think you will be probably on one of the first two categories (but in case of missed connection).